# Adding HTML code into a list

Tags: java, url, arraylist, bufferedreader

So I am trying to make a scraper as my first project. I am fairly new and I don't really understand the code that I wrote. Although I don't understand it, there does not seem to be any errors in eclipse.

The code I wrote is suppose to read the html source file and add it line by line into an array-list until it can't and then return the list. I really don't know if it is simple or not but I have no clue why it isn't working.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;



public class Scraper {
    public static void main(String [] args)throws Exception{

        get_url_source("https://statsroyale.com/clan/99VUU8Y");
}

    public static List<String> get_url_source(String URL)throws Exception {

        List <String> source = new ArrayList <>();

        URL stats = new URL("https://statsroyale.com/clan/99VUU8Y");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stats.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            source.add(inputLine);

        return source;
  }
}
```

As well as I really apologize if the formatting is wrong. Still trying to learn how the formatting works and what goes where. (It's not as simple as it seems)

The ERROR msg is long but here is is...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://statsroyale.com/clan/99VUU8Y
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at Scraper.get_url_source(Scraper.java:21)
    at Scraper.main(Scraper.java:13)
```

Comment: what is a 403 error - see https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989

Answer (score 0):

The site is checking your user agent to see if is accessed by bots,
to trick the site that you are a normal user you have to change the user agent
in this way:

```
    URL stats = new URL("https://statsroyale.com/clan/99VUU8Y");

    HttpsURLConnection statsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) stats.openConnection();
    statsConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
    statsConnection.connect();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(statsConnection.getInputStream()));
```